# Associative container that allows specification of seperate comparator and ordering functor

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, stl, set

I am looking for a container that allows me to specify separate functions for ordering and equivalence. `std::set` allows the specification of 1 comparator function. 
Ideally I want to sort on a criteria, but searching through the set, I want to use another criteria for matching. I hacked this solution by using a map that stores iterators inserted to the set. But I am wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use two containers (that you manually keep in synch) or else `boost::multi_index`.

Since elements in a `set` are never relocated and iterators never invalidated, your solution with a map of key->iterator is probably about as good as any other two-container solution. You could perhaps store a map of key->pointer instead.

Or of course you could use just the `std::set`, and search for elements using `std::find` or `std::find_if`. The search will take time linear in the size of the set.

Comment: However I am not sure, either find or find_if would work. Say I have a single member of the key that I want to search on, find will not work. find_if only supports a unary function predicate. so I can't pass in anything to compare to the key. I have not tried writing the find/find_if code, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Pradyot: look into how to write functor classes, `find_if` can take an object that holds a pointer or reference to the thing you're looking for, and uses it in `operator()`. Same goes for `find`, you can pass it an object that does anything you like in `operator==`.

Answer (score 4):

Try `boost::multi_index_container`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

> The Boost Multi-index Containers Library provides a class template
>   named multi_index_container which enables the construction of
>   containers maintaining one or more indices with different sorting and
>   access semantics. Indices provide interfaces similar to those of STL
>   containers, making using them familiar. The concept of multi-indexing
>   over the same collection of elements is borrowed from relational
>   database terminology and allows for the specification of complex data
>   structures in the spirit of multiply indexed relational tables where
>   simple sets and maps are not enough. A wide selection of indices is
>   provided, modeled after analogous STL containers like std::set,
>   std::list and hashed sets.
>
> Boost.MultiIndex features additional functionalities, like subobject
>   searching, range querying and in-place updating of elements, which
>   make it a convenient replacement for std::set and set::multiset even
>   when no multi-indexing capabilities are needed.

It supports what you are looking for exactly.  See the section on [multiple sorting](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort).